# Displaying a portion of a table in a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010

On my first worksheet in the workbook, I have a large table with multiple columns and rows (roughly a 1000 rows and 20 columns).

I was wondering if it is possible to display part of this table in another worksheet in the workbook based on the criteria from one of the columns in the main table.

To help explain this, I will use an example from the actual workbook.

On worksheet 1 (called *General Employee Info* which is the main table), in Column A each row has a unique number identifying an employee (each employee has their own ID number).

Column B holds their office location (a city/municipality). Column C holds the state the office is in. Column D holds their salary amount per year.

There are multiple more columns with this type of employee information, which needs no further explanation.

**My question is**, can I label Sheet 2 in the workbook `"New York State"` and have that sheet display all the same information as Sheet 1 (all the same columns) but only display the employees that work in the state of New York?

And then have another sheet labelled `"California"` and have only the employees that work in California on that sheet and so on... In other words, have a separate sheet for each state.

It's essentially like filtering the main table using the State column to show only one state, but I want the results in a separate sheet instead of filtering the main table which holds all the information.

I was thinking of using a pivot table in each new sheet, but am not sure that's the right approach.

Is this possible? I hope I was clear in explaining the problem.

Comment: You can use use the `Camera` tool to show views of your main data on other sheets. They remain linked so updating the main sheet also updates the views. See [HERE](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_camera_tool/) for some info on using it.

Comment: hi bob, if you could edit your question to put i a few paragraphs it might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 26):

I really recommend using the excel tables feature if you are using Excel 2013 or later as a starting point. Tables rock for many reasons, including making your sheets more readable for users, and making formulas for things like INDEX/MATCH much less error prone.

Once the tables are in place with the main data, to subset  I use the [data modeling capability](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-a-Data-Model-in-Excel-87E7A54C-87DC-488E-9410-5C75DBCB0F7B) to link back to those tables.

These steps in Excel 2013 - version active around 2018.  It's changed in Office 365 (see below)

1. create a sheet, or go where you want the table in your current sheet.
2. click the 'data' tab and select "connections" in the connections section.
3. from there select the drop down on the add button and select **Add to Data Model..** 
   [Connections Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5iPz.png)
4. Click the tables tab.  Click the table you want.
5. now close the dialog
6. on the data tab, click **Existing Connections** in the "get external connections" of the data tab.
7. Click the Table tab
8. Select the table you want
9. Select the table radio button
10. hit return (or new sheet or a different cell if that's what you want)
11. **poof** your table from another sheet is now reflected in the current worksheet.

At this point you can subset using data slicing, hide columns, insert new columns with new formulas on the right or left edges of the table, etc.

You do have to refresh this separately using the 'refresh all' button on the tool bar.

In Excel as of October 2019 as (Thank you Josh for point this out!) It's gotten better as they include some of the 'power' tools in excel, and made a toolbar item that gets to the functions.  Specifically:

1. Create a Table with the source data by selecting the data in the sheet, and using insert Table.
2. Select the Table
3. On the Data Tab click the small icon in the lower middle with the tooltip "from Table/Range"
4. This will Open the Power Query Editor.  [Microsoft has a tutorial; but it looks a little different now](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-excel-table-or-range-power-query-67538004-cd12-4b61-9cee-8720db1c7136)
5. After you've built your query; press "Close and Load" in the editor.  Without options it will create a new sheet.  If you choose the option with the ellipsis you have a few other options.

Comment: As usual, it is not possible to follow along on the Mac version. Office is one of the few cross OS programs where the UI is completely different between the two. https://imgur.com/a/XrMmmQV

Comment: I'm using Office 365 in 2019 and the options weren't exactly the same. Basically I just started at step 6, where "Existing Connections" is now in the "Get & Transform Data" group. My table was already there in the Table tab.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Updated to match the current UI.

Comment: Why 2013 or newer? 2007 and 2010 also support tables

Comment: What if you have three tables you want to show on one worksheet but you want them to dynamicly resize as is appropriate to the amount of date in each table? Like have the first table go for as many rows as it needs and then leave a blank space and start the next table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variation of what you are trying to do here : http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/

If all your data is on Sheet1 and you define a range (CTRL F3) which contains all the elements called [tbl]
In Sheet2 In cell A1 enter the column number that you are searching Sheet1 
In Sheet2 in cell B1 enter the search criteria (ie, the State you want to filter by)
From Cell A2 to Z1000 (for example) enter the following array formula (So enter using CTRL SHIFT RETURN)

```
=INDEX(tbl, SMALL(IF((INDEX(tbl, , $A$1, 1)=$B$1), ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1, ""), ROWS(A2:$A$2)), , 1)
```

One key point to note in the execution of this is to create the array for the first row first, CTRL SHIFT RETURN to create it, then drag it down. Doing it in the wrong order won't increment the row counter at the end of the function properly. Just follow the instructions at the link at the start of this post and your should get it.

Answer (score 0):

When you asked the question, it was a pain. For those looking for this in 2023 or later, now it's easy. Using Filter and Lambda (in Excel 365 or 2021, unavailable in older versions)  you can do it super easily. This assumes your sheet name is the exact value you want to filter on. Using your example, New York State.

First, for readability, you want to make a Lambdafunction to get sheet name. This is not strictly necessary but will save a lot of trouble later.

1. Open Excel and go to Formulas > Name Manager > New.
2. In the "New Name" dialog box, enter a name for your function, for
   example, "GetSheetName".
3. In the "Refers to" field, enter the following formula and click OK:

> =LAMBDA(ref, MID(CELL("filename", ref),FIND("]",CELL("filename", ref))+1,255))

"ref" is a parameter passed to the calculation. When you see ref in the calculation, it is going to use whatever data you enter in the formula. For our purposes, we're just using the cell we enter the filter function is. But literally any cell reference on the worksheet will be fine.

Next, go to the New york sheet and enter the following filter function in cell A1:

> =FILTER(General Employee Info[#All], General Employee Info[State/Municipality]=GetSheetName(A1), "No match")

This will automatically populate the sheet with the info from your table where the Municipality info matches the sheet name. You can further mess with it using the other array functions. But if you're trying to do this in 2023, it's DEAD easy.